# Anti-ideals in $\Bbb{Z}$ form a matroid, so all maximal anti-ideals are in bijection?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, ideals, integers, matroids

Let $A \subset \Bbb{Z}$.  $A$ is a called an **anti-ideal** when

1. $x, y \in A \implies x - y \notin A$.
2. $z \in \Bbb{Z}, z \neq \pm 1, a \in A \implies za \notin A$.

[Matroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid) are something in graph theory that becomes important when studying greedy algorithms for instance.  But there are many applications and the theory of matroids has books written about it. I know because I own one called "Matroid Theory" by D.J.A. Welsh, but I don't read it, lol.

> **Conjecture.**  *The collection $\mathcal{A}$ of anti-ideals of $\Bbb{Z}$ form a matroid.*

*Proof*. $\varnothing \in \mathcal{A}$ satisfies 1. & 2. vacuously.   And clearly $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under taking subsets.  Thus all we need to prove is that if $A, B \in \mathcal{A}$ are anti-ideals such that $|A| \gt |B|$, then there exists $x \in A \setminus B$ such that $B \cup \{x\} \in \mathcal{A}$.  This is true since if no such $x$ exists then we can say that either $A - B = \{ a - b : a \in A, b \in B\} \subset B$ or $z A \subset B$ for all $z \in \Bbb{Z}$ each of which implies $|A| \leq |B|$ since $f(x) = x - b$ and $g(x) = zx : A \to B$ are always injective.  $\square$

Can you please verify this argument for me?

Thanks! :D

> **Corollary.** *All maximal anti-ideals are in bijection.*

---

By the way, the set of of all odd primes is an anti-ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way for no such $x$ to exist: if $A \subset \{zb: z \in \Bbb Z_{\text{non_unit }}, b \in B\} \cup B$. This tells you nothing about the relative sizes of $A$ and $B$; in particular, if $B = \{-1, 1\}$ then $\{zb: z \in \Bbb Z_{\text{non_unit }}, b \in B\} = \Bbb Z \setminus B$.

Comment: Are you sure about the $\cup B$ in the first sentence?  Please explain, how do you know that that is an anti-ideal?

Comment: @RollupandsmokeAdjoint we're trying to add an element of $A$ to $B$; that element can't already be a member of $B$, hence the $\cup B$.

Comment: So, you're implying any $A \subset B (\Bbb{Z}\setminus \{-1, 1\}) \cup B$ is an anti-ideal?

Comment: I'll come back to this later and study it some more today

Comment: @RollupandsmokeAdjoint no. Remember what we're trying to do: add one element $x$ of $A$ to $B$ such that $B \cup \{x\}$ is an anti-ideal. But if $B = \{1, -1\}$ then $B$ is a maximal anti-ideal (see your other question) so this isn't possible

Comment: Please see my updated (new) question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2980848/26327